# Outlook Event API : At least one property failed validation error

Tags: json, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm creating an Outlook event via Outlook API by providing following JSON input :

```
{  
   "subject":"bla bla bla",
   "start":{  
      "dateTime":"2018-01-14T17:00:00",
      "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
   },
    "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "janets@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Name": "Janet Schorr"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I'm getting the following error response :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorPropertyValidationFailure",
        "message": "At least one property failed validation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6f3d1676-77cc-49b0-87a2-b96b6ed1f15d",
            "date": "2018-01-12T05:25:10"
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass the **end attribute** in the above JSON, the event is created successfully. The below JSON works fine :

```
{  
   "subject":"bla bla bla",
   "start":{  
      "dateTime":"2018-01-14T17:00:00",
      "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
   },
   "end":{  
          "dateTime":"2018-01-14T17:00:00",
          "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
       },
    "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "janets@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Name": "Janet Schorr"
      },
      "Type": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it required to pass an **end attribute** for event creation? Or is there something wrong with the above JSON input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `end` is required. Outlook/Exchange don't support events with no end date :)